# Validation error while trying to migrate on-prem SQL Database to Azure SQL managed instance using Azure DMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have successfully created Azure Database Migration Project under Azure Database Migration Service
during the last phase of the project I am getting validation error

> No valid full backup found for database ***DB-NAME***. Either there was no full backup file present or Database Migration Service could not access the file.

I am using windows Administrator as the authentication for SQL Server and the administrator has full permission over the shared folder which has the database back too. Still getting error not able to understand where I made mistake.

Comment: Besides your database files themselves, do you have a full backup of the database available? (I'm not experienced with the DMS, just going off what the error says though.)

Comment: yes I have the full Database backedup.

Comment: Have you setup working network connectivity between your on-premises database infrastructure and Azure?  Have you completed all the prerequisites listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/dms/pre-reqs)?

Comment: yes network connectivity is working we are able to select the database from source,the issue is accessing the dbbackup file from shared folder which is were we are getting error.